# c# datatable select case when error

Tags: c#, datatable

I got a filtering problem when I try to order it by case when

which is coded like

```
 dt.Select("1=1 ", "CASE WHEN ParcaKodu LIKE '%8200436025%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ")
```

Comment: Sorting and filtering this way is a local thing and has almost nothing to do with the syntax you might know from sql. I don't think the CASE construct is valid here. But you just say that you have a problem but not what problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `CASE` construct to filter records within C#. There's only [a limited number of syntax elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use.